# Google Calendar API reporting multiple all-day events when web interface only shows one each day

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I was using the code below to update events from a Google Sheet.  The problem occurred when the code was reporting that there were existing events in the calendar for a specific day but those events would not show in the web interface.  I changed the code to delete all events and always insert a new event instead of updating and that works as expected.

But that does not explain how the API can report that events exist while no events are showing in the web interface. Is this a bug in the API?

**update:** The real issue has been determined to be that the API call to `getEventsForDay(d)` is returning events for two days at a time.  So there are no missing events.  But I still have not figured out how to get events returned for a single day.  All of the events in this calendar were inserted via the API.

```
function updateCalold(cell,title, calendar) {

  var d;

  try {
    d = new Date(cell.getValue()); 
  }
  catch(err) {
    return false;
  }
  var txt_date = Utilities.formatDate(d, "EST", "yyyy-MM-dd");

  var events = calendar.getEventsForDay(d);

  if ( events.length == 0 ) {
    var event = calendar.createAllDayEvent(title, d);
  }
  else {
    for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
      events[i].setVisibility(CalendarApp.Visibility.PUBLIC);
      if (events[i].getTitle() !== title) {
        events[i].setTitle(title);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: when you get more than 1 event are these events strictly identical ?(same type, same startTime etc ?) I use calendar a lot in scripts and have never met any issue, this api is really reliable (IMO!).It is not impossible that you have issues with time zone or daylight savings...

Comment: These were all-day events.

Comment: That's not a reason it can't be a problem : when you call getEventsForDay(d) and d is a date with a different tz (because of DL saving) the request is overlapping on the next day. Replace EST with Session.getScriptTimeZone or getSpreadsheetTimeZone() and check the result.

Comment: Thanks, @Sergeinsas  The issue is definitely that the `calendar.getEventsForDay(d)` code is returning events for multiple days.  Both Session.getScriptTimeZone or getSpreadsheetTimeZone() return Etc/GMT.  I've tried creating the date for d in code with `new Date(2014,7,20)` and I still get the same error.

Comment: Take a look at these issues, it might interest you [issues AllDayEvent](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list?can=1&q=createAllDayEvent%28%29&colspec=Stars+Opened+ID+Type+Status+Summary+Component+Owner&cells=tiles)  That said, have you checked all your TZ setting (calendar, script) and are all the dates having this issue ? equally in summer and winter ?

Comment: Seems you are right... sorry for insisting before testing.. see answer below :-)

Comment: This [issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=234&can=1&q=createAllDayEvent()&sort=status&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner)  seems to suggest that this is a bug.

Comment: The issue you refer to does not offer a reliable solution as it dicuss mainly the event creation and no way to get only the right event... my solution does. Have you tested it with the right startup config (see edit)

Comment: moreover, it complains that events are overlapping on the next day. Your issue is that you get events from the day before... quite different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Calendar (API or Web) inserts all day events with a start date matching the day that is displayed in the web interface.  The end date will be the following date.  When calling `calendar.getEventsForDay(d);` the api will return events where either **start date** or **end date** match the date `d`.

What this means is that regardless of time frames, if you have single day, all day events in a block of consecutive days, the API will correctly return one event on the first day in the block and will return 2 for each day after that.

The API also provides `event.getAllDayStartDate()`. I used this code to test the events to ensure I was operating on the correct day.

Below is my final solution.

```
function updateEvent(cell,title, calendar) {

  var d;
  try {
    // extract date from sheet cell
    d = new Date(cell.getValue()); 
    Logger.log("updateCal: %s",d);
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log("Not a date: %s", cell.getValue());
    Logger.log(err);
    return false;
  }

  var events = calendar.getEventsForDay(d);
  var foundEvent = false;
  Logger.log("numEvents: %s", events.length);

  if ( events.length > 0 ) {
    for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
      if ( events[i].isAllDayEvent() && 
           events[i].getAllDayStartDate().getDay() === d.getDay() ) { 
        foundEvent = true
        if (events[i].getTitle() !== title) {
          events[i].setTitle(title);
          Logger.log('index: %s ,updated title on event %s', i, d); 
        } 
      }
    }
  }

  if ( !foundEvent ){
    var event = calendar.createAllDayEvent(title, d);
    Logger.log('day was empty, inserted: %s on %s',title, d);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is interesting, I almost never use `allDayEvents` nor `getEventsForDay` so I didn't notice that but I does apparently be an issue...

`getEvents()` is returning events that end the day before the startTime defined at 0 hours when these events end at 0 hours the day before... if I change the startTime in getEvents by adding the TimeZone offset then it works fine.

So the issue is related to TimeZone but I can't see exactly why it behaves so.

Anyway, while I'm still searching the exact origin I found a workaround that returns exact results.

I'll try to keep this post updated when I come across better explanations.

Here is the code to demonstrate how the solution works.  To get the error, simply replace `offset` value with 0 and you will again get multiple events.

[Test SS here, make a copy to try it](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u2g83P8vAtjOcbrTIEgpeNxz-T-7AyWoV5hMxYcHC8U/edit?usp=sharing)

Conditions to perform the test in your default calendar : The problem occurs only with `AllDayEvents`, and you must have another `OneDayEvent` for yesterday of course (in your default calendar). Also, set the cell A1 manually to today's date !
[image]

```
function test(){
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('A1');// A1 had a test date that I set manually to today's date for test
  var title = 'test event renamed by script @ '+Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'HH:mm:ss');

  var result = updateCalold(cell,title, calendar);
  Logger.log('result from function = '+result.join('\n\n'));
}


function updateCalold(cell,title, calendar) {
  var d;
  var result = [];
  result.push('\n');
  Logger.log(new Date().toString().split('GMT+')[1])
  var offset = Number(new Date().toString().split('GMT+')[1].substr(0,2));
  Logger.log(offset);
  //offset=0; // uncomment this to get the error
  try {
    d = new Date(cell.getValue()); 
  }
  catch(err) {
    return false;
  }
  var startTime = new Date(d.setHours(offset,0,0,0));
  var endTime = new Date(new Date(d.setHours(0,0,0,0)).setDate(d.getDate()+1));
  var events = calendar.getEvents(startTime, endTime);
  Logger.log('startTime = '+startTime+'  endTime = '+endTime);
  Logger.log('events.length = '+events.length)
  if ( events.length == 0 ) {
    var event = calendar.createAllDayEvent(title, d);
  }
  else {
    for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
      events[i].setVisibility(CalendarApp.Visibility.PUBLIC);
      if (events[i].getTitle() !== title) {
        events[i].setTitle(title+' event nr'+i);
        result.push(events[i].getTitle()+' starting @ '+events[i].getStartTime()+' ending @ '+events[i].getEndTime());
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

**EDIT :** below it a capture of the log when offset=0, ie with the error :
[image]

**EDIT 2 :** thoughts...

Thinking about that, one can consider that an event ending today at 00:00 could be considered (in a way) to belong to today's events from 00:00... that I could eventually accept even if I don't like this logic but when I start getting events 1 hour later (for example, startTime = 01 AM), I should not get events that ended 1 hour before !

The bug (IMHO) is that we must use an offset value = GMT offset to get it right... any smaller value will capture events from the day before ! in my case (GMT+2) I  get an wrong result with offset=1 as well.

This is going to end up in the issue tracker I'm afraid, unless someone can explain...

**EDIT 3 :** If these spreadsheet AND script AND calendar are all set to GMT0000 (GMT0 without daylight savings) then everything works fine without any modification, even using `getEventsForDay()`.  See [test SS here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NmeLtT4_9jRzaueojVQURDEnqFm35fo23KG8hYdJj6w/edit?usp=sharing), testable with your default calendar set to **GMT0** without daylight savings, *just for test* of course since all your events are going to show wrong dates !!! unless you live in a region without DL saving and uses GMT0 but I don't think this is possible ;-).

Comment: When I run this code, with or without `offset=0;` commented out, I get a single 1 hour event with an updated title.

Comment: The problem occurs only with AllDay events, and you must have another OneDay event for yesterday of course (in your default calendar) - see illustration in updated anwser

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and implemented the fix you describe.  However digging some dates out of google's UK holiday calendar shows that some of them will come back as GMT-0000, so your code will not work (as it's looking for "GMT+")

```
Mon May 25 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST) Spring Bank Holiday
Mon Aug 03 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST) Summer Bank Holiday
Mon Aug 31 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST) Summer Bank Holiday
Fri Dec 25 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0000 (GMT) Christmas Day
Sat Dec 26 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0000 (GMT) Boxing Day
Mon Dec 28 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0000 (GMT) Bank Holiday
```

A simple fix is to search for "GMT" and take 3 characters i.e.

```
var offset = Number(new Date().toString().split('GMT')[1].substr(0,3));
```

I agree, that strictly speaking, an all-day event from yesterday that finishes at 0000 would appear in getEventsForDay(today) - even though that is counter-intuitive.  I do feel though that it must be a bug to have that same event appear if I getEvents("00:00:01","23:59:59").  We should not have to add an offset to get that to work!

I think we're looking at two problems here.  Firstly that an "all day" event should end at 23:59:59 today rather than 00:00:00 tomorrow and secondly the above problem.